# Creating Customized rule for FxCop

Tags: fxcop, fxcop-customrules

Need help for creating a fxcop rule for following statement:

```
"Do not cast values from different domains"
```

I have googled for this statement and get some info from following microsoft site:

[Click Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b63aadf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

It says

```
"•Do not cast values from different domains. Casts operate within a particular domain of values. For example, numbers and strings are different domains. "
```

But i am not getting any idea how can I make a generic rule for this.
I am building some customized rules which are not available in FxCop.

Comment: Did you not notice that you found a .NET 1.1 article?

Comment: Can you post some sample code?